# Why won't .profile be executed?

Tags: bash

[here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html) is some good docs that I also misread; quoted here:

> 3.1.2.3. ~/.profile
>
> In the absence of ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile is
>   read. It can hold the same configurations, which are then also
>   accessible by other shells. Mind that other shells might not
>   understand the Bash syntax.

However, I want to know why is `.profile` not executed? The author made the note `other shells may not understand the syntax` and that makes good sense but what if I wanted to make the call anyway? Would I be required to put the calling code in the `.bash??` file? I guess that makes sense too except that would be one more file for me to maintain.

I realize this may be an opinion question but maybe there is some historical documentation which will create understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `.profile` is a generic profile file for any shell interpreter which will be used when running `bash` if there is no *specific* profile (ie: `.bash_profile`).

One can change the `.profile` content to whatever he want but it's risky since it's used by others shells, and putting bash code in it would be harmful with other shells. That's why you can read:

> Mind that other shells might not understand the Bash syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid question, but I'll try it

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

? :)

Comment: No. Shell profiles are sourced, they need not be executable.